# Perform any task on a dataframe based on the column name, which is input by the user

Tags: r, dataframe

A system deals with extracting all the column names of a data.frame that is given as an input and the user gets to chose either of the variables from the input dataset. Considering the `mtcars` dataset, if it is given as an input, the user can chose from its columns which are extracted as :

```
#to get all the column names and type
colNamesTypes<- as.data.frame(sapply(mtcars, typeof))
colNamesTypes<-cbind(Variable=rownames(colNamesTypes),colNamesTypes)
colnames(colNamesTypes)<-c("Variable","Type")
rownames(colNamesTypes)<-NULL
```

The column names are:

```
carnames mpg    cyl disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs  am  gear    carb
```

(I converted the row.names of mtcars to a proper column - `carnames` for convenience sake)

Lets say the user selects, `mpg` and `hp` and wants to find the sum of those two variables. We can do it in the following way :

```
UserVar1 <- "mpg"
UserVar2 <- "hp"
summary1 = group_by(mtcars,mpg,hp)
summary1 = summarise(summary1, 
                      Sum_mpg = sum(mpg),
                      Sum_hp = sum(hp))
```

The above statements are sure enough to give the users their required analyses. But the problem here is that the `group_by()` and  `summarise()` statements are not dynamic i.e., if the user wants analyses for some other variables, then R cannot know the new variables that are selected.

So, how do I ask my `summarise()` to take `UserVar1` and `UserVar2` as the arguments, instead of the hard-coded column names?

---

I have tried using `mtcars[UserVar1]` which is analogous to `mtcars["mpg"]` but the output is in a data.frame form not a vector form like `mtcars$mpg` gives and hence I get an error in the `summarise()` statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
summary1 = group_by(mtcars, v1 = unlist(mtcars[UserVar1]), 
                    v2 = unlist(mtcars[UserVar2]) )
summary1 = summarise(summary1, 
Sum_mpg = sum(v1),
Sum_hp = sum(v2) )
```

`v1` and `v2`are the names given to the vectors in the `group_by` function.

```
unlist(mtcars[UserVar1])
```

gives you a vector

Comment: So, how do I pass it??

`summary1 = group_by(mtcars,unlist(mtcars[UserVar1]),unlist(mtcars[UserVar2]))`

`summary1 = summarise(summary1, Sum_mpg = sum(mtcars[UserVar1])),Sum_hp = sum(mtcars[UserVar1])))`

Comment: But that doesn't give me the same output as 
`summary1 = summarise(summary1, Sum_mpg = sum(mpg),Sum_hp = sum(hp))`

Answer (score 0):

```
summary1 = summarise(summary1, 
                      Sum_mpg = sum(summary1[,UserVar1]),
                      Sum_hp = sum(summary1[,UserVar2]))
```

Gives the same output as providing the unquoted column names.

I prefer this piping method though:

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(mpg,hp) %>% 
  summarise(Sum_mpg = sum(.[,UserVar1]),
            Sum_hp = sum(.[,UserVar2]))->summary1
```

Comment: Fantastic. But I am not able to get proper results on `group_by(mtcars,mtcars[,UserVar1],mtcars[,UserVar2]`. That statement actually adds up a new column to the original dataframe and my subsequent `summarise()` statement doesn't give me proper output..